# Passing dataframe column vale as parameter in get url python

Tags: python, json, pandas

I am trying to pass a column value as url parameter in loop and I am also trying to put result into json file and later convert into excel. I need to do this without creating any function.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import json
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

df = pd.read_excel('C:/Users/one.xlsx',converters={'name':str}) 
df = df['name']
df.head()

dd=df.values
user=b"user"
passwd=b'pass'
auth_values = (user, passwd)
for i in dd:
    ur='http://xyz.co&name='
    url =ur + str(dd)
    response = (requests.get(url, auth=auth_values).text)
    response_json = json.loads(response)
    response_json=json.dumps(response,ensure_ascii=True)
    writeFile =open('C:/Users/file1.json', 'w')
writeFile.write(response_json)
writeFile.close()
print(url)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import json
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

df = pd.read_excel('C:/Users/one.xlsx',converters={'name':str}) 
df = df['name']
df.head()

dd=df.values
user=b"user"
passwd=b'pass'
auth_values = (user, passwd)

with open('C:/Users/file1.json', 'w') as writeFile: 
    for i in dd:
       ur='http://xyz.co&name='
       url =ur + str(i)
       response = requests.get(url, auth=auth_values).text
       response_json = json.loads(response)
       response_json=json.dumps(response,ensure_ascii=True)
       writeFile.write(response_json)
       print(url)
```

For export to excel:

```
df = pd.read_excel('C:/Users/one.xlsx',converters={'name':str}) 
df = df['name']
dd=df.values

user=b"user"
passwd=b'pass'
auth_values = (user, passwd)

df_base = None
for i in dd:
    ur='http://xyz.co&name='
    url =ur + str(i)
    response = requests.get(url, auth=auth_values).text
    df = pd.read_json(response)

    if df_base is None:
        df_base = df
    else:
        df_base.append(df)

    print(url)

df_base.to_excel("C:/Users/output.xlsx")
```

Comment: Hey thanks it working ,can you please tell me how can i transfer the json data into excel. i checked the json file its on text format with new line characters

Comment: Or you can help me to directly direct the output to excel file with help of dataframe

Comment: `to_excel` function can be use. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html

Comment: i am getting an error: Excel does not support datetimes with timezones. Please ensure that datetimes are timezone unaware before writing to Excel.

Comment: Could you share a sample data of the response?

Comment: Can't share the data but can tell that it contains timestamp the data is nda and the result is multiple json responses combined together